# Unable to install software on windows 10 minion

Tags: salt-stack

I trying to get the master to install software on the minion but it doesn't seem like its working. When I try a debug it looks like the problem is the following:

```
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
```

Not sure how to go about fixing it. For more information my salt master version is 2015.5.10 (lithium) and my minion version is 2015.5.1. Also the complete debug log is:

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/master.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: ECS-141abdb2.ecs.ads.autodesk.com
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/master.d/master.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master.d/master.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: ECS-141abdb2.ecs.ads.autodesk.com
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'_stamp': '2016-10-31T15:49:34.567058'}
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.get_load
[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20161031084934590375 sent to set(['ds']) will timeout at 08:49:39.5975                                          53
[DEBUG   ] jid 20161031084934590375 return from ds
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm new to this :)

Command used was:

```
sudo salt '<minion>' pkg.install 'chrome'
```

Comment: you do not need a `.saltrc` for the user. It is something like `.bashrc`. May you provide which command you execute, that does not work as excpected?

Comment: Hey @dahrens i updated with the command I used. I expected it to install the software.

Comment: does this also don't work: `sudo salt '<minion>' pkg.install chrome` (without `'` around chrome). If this doesn't, please tell us about the target OS.

Comment: @dahrens no it doesn't and also target OS is Windows 10.

Comment: would you mind to change the questions title to something more speaking like 'Unable to install software on windows 10 minion' as the answer is only related to that topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of windows you need to include some magic for this to work properly. Did you followed the instructions [written here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html)? A short summary of the docs content

```
# prepare your master to know about the win repos
salt-run winrepo.update_git_repos
# tell all connected windows minions to refresh
salt -G 'os:windows' pkg.refresh_db
# list available packages
salt -G 'os:windows' pkg.list_pkgs
# ask your minion for known chrome versions
salt '<minion id>' pkg.available_version chrome
# and finally install it; use version=x.x.x in case of a specific one.
salt '<minion id>' pkg.install 'chrome'
```